# Trying to learn SherPoint development with Sharepoint.com

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-addin, visual-web-part

Because I don't have the hardware  or license i bought Sharepoint Online from sharepoint.com

I've just started out, and want to for instance create a poll. I Visual Studio I have two choices:

- App for Sharepoint
- Visual Web Part

But I think Visual Web Part is the way to solve it, but when I select it Visual Studio says:

"The required version of SharePoint Foundation 2013 or SharePoint Server 2013 is not installed on this system, SharePoint must installed on the local system to develop SharePoint solutions"

I found and downloaded SharePoint Foundation 2013 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35488), but nothing happens when I click "Install SharePoint Foundation".

I dont want to install Sharepoint locally as I dont have the hardware specs or the license to do so, but now Im thinking the online version u get for $3 at Sharepoint cant be used for dev?

Comment: For SharePoint online you should focus on apps!

Comment: @Robert Lindgren What are apps? Whole website solutions?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: You really are limited to just AppParts without someone else developing the WebPart you need.  ClientWebParts are peculiar.  I have not been able to do as much as when i have access to the backend with the ServerSide capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop apps for SahrePoint Online you should select 'App for SharePoint' instead of Visual Web Part. You can choose from three types of hosting options, SharePoint-hosted, Provider-hosted or Autohosted. To know what are the differences between these options take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx.

If you go for SharePoint-hosted, you can create an app part by adding a Client Web Part (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921%28v=office.15%29.aspx). In Provider-hosted and Autohosted you can deploy your web parts by including them in a module.

You got this message:

> "The required version of SharePoint Foundation 2013 or SharePoint
>   Server 2013 is not installed on this system, SharePoint must installed
>   on the local system to develop SharePoint solutions"

because you selected Visual Web Part while you didn't install SharePoint On-Premise. That is not really necessary if your purpose is to develop SharePoint solutions for SharePoint Online.